# How to retrieve child data in firebase with the key?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in firebase .
I want to fetch child data along with the key .
The following code i have tried in nodejs Environment.

```
  var firebase = require("firebase");

    firebase.initializeApp({
       databaseURL: "https://some.firebaseio.com/"
    });


    var customer = firebase.database().ref().child('customer');

    const fname = "name";
    const lname = "title";
    customer.orderByChild("partnerFirstName").equalTo(fname).on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
       console.log(snapshot.val());

       var fn = snapshot.val().partnerFirstName;

       var custdata = snapshot.val();

       console.log(custdata);
       console.log("FirstName:"+fn);

       if (custdata.partnerFirstName === fn) {
         console.log(custdata);

       }


     });
```

The output is as follows

```
    {
      createdAt: '2018-03-20T23:25:35.212Z',
      partnerEmail: 'beard@yahoo.com',
      partnerFirstName: 'name',
      partnerGender: 'male',
      partnerLastName: 'title',
      partnerPhone: '444-602-4444',
      profilePicture: 'assets/profile_icon.png',
      uid: 'x99wl8kkmJSENpNdVMXTXCh7amy2' }
      FirstName: name
```

In this case we are not getting the key value of the record but firstname is coming without any error .

But when we tried the following code the key is coming along with  data but firstname is coming as undefined

```
 var customer = firebase.database().ref().child('customer');

        const fname = "Name";
        const lname = "Title";
        customer.orderByChild("partnerFirstName").equalTo(fname).on('value', function (snapshot) {
           console.log(snapshot.val());

           var fn = snapshot.val().partnerFirstName;

           var custdata = snapshot.val();

           console.log(custdata);
           console.log("FirstName:"+fn);
           if (custdata.partnerFirstName === fn) {
             console.log(custdata);

           }


         });
```

The output is as follows

```
{ '-L84iSPyr9bPvnJZ6BgV':
   { 
     createdAt: '2018-03-20T23:25:35.212Z',
     partnerEmail: 'beard@yahoo.com',
     partnerFirstName: 'name',
     partnerGender: 'male',
     partnerLastName: 'title',
     partnerPhone: '444-602-4444',
     profilePicture: 'assets/profile_icon.png',
     uid: 'x99wl8kkmJSENpNdVMXTXCh7amy2' } }
     FirstName: undefined
```

**How to get child data along with key?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace your code with

```
customer.orderByChild("partnerFirstName").equalTo(fname).on('value', 
    function (snapshot) {

       var snap = snapshot.val();
       var key = Object.keys(snap);
       var custdata = snap[key];
       var fn = snap[key].partnerFirstName;

       if (custdata.partnerFirstName === fn) {
         console.log(custdata);
       }
 });
```

to return both the key and the child

Answer (score 2):

To get the key, try the following:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("customer").orderByChild("partnerFirstName").equalTo(fname);
ref.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
snapshot.forEach(function(child){
var key = child.key; 
var partnerName=child.val().partnerFirstName;

  });
});
```

In the above, you iterate inside the children of `customer` and then retrieve the key using `var key = child.key;`

Comment: It wont come in perfect format because we have to iterate in angular as service

Comment: ,please see the second output ,we want data in json (key and value)   format  but ''FirstName ' is returning undefined

Comment: we have tried your above code .please see our first code, in that case we are unable retrieve  key .but we can retrieve value but in second code case we can retrieve key and value but cant retrieve FirstName

Comment: how are u unable to retrieve the key in the answer? https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#key, When you iterate then you will be able to get that pushid. Then to get `partnerFirstName` just do as in the answer, to be able to access the children. If you want the `FirstName` which according to your question seems to be a direct child under `customer` and sibling with the pushid the do `var name=snapshot.val().FirstName;` to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks  to  all .I am  successfully solved issues of this code .My main motive is to use above code to fetch json format through firebase cloud function.and it is working fine .I successfully searched firstname and lastname in the url and it fetched the corresponding record .

```
exports.getCustomerbyname2 = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');


    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
      res.status(204).send('');
    }
    const fname = req.query.fname;
    const lname = req.query.lname;

    var customer=admin.database().ref().child('customer'); 
    customer.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {
        var fname1 = snapshot.val().partnerFirstName; 
        var lname1 = snapshot.val().partnerLastName; 

       customer.orderByChild('partnerFirstName').equalTo(fname).once('value', function(snapshot) {


            var arr=[];
            if (fname1 === fname && lname1===lname) {
                arr.push(snapshot.val());
                console.log(snapshot.val());
                res.status(200).json({ customer: arr});


            }else{
                res.status(200).send('ERROR : ' + errorObject);

            }

        },function(errorObject){
            console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
           // res.status(200).send('ERROR : ' + errorObject);
        });

    });

});
```